# How to add custom TypeScript Global Interfaces

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I have several interfaces that I use across an entire CommonJS structured typescript project. I would like to create a global file called "interfaces.ts" ... Rather than having to import the interface or add a reference into every .ts file (boilerplate), is there a way to globally declare it, maybe in the tsconfig.json file?

I am aware there is a global definition file called lib.d.ts, which is basically globally declared interfaces. I realize I can probably modify this file, but was looking for a better way (abstraction).

Edit: I should probably note that I'm currently using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way `tsconfig.json` works by default. Create a `tsconfig.json` in the root of your project without a "files" property. You may need to restart VS Code for it to recognize the `tsconfig.json`.

> If no "files" property is present in a tsconfig.json, the compiler defaults to including all files the containing directory and subdirectories. When a  "files"  property is specified, only those files are included.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/1692

Comment: Ahh I see... all I had to do was remove the "export" when defining the interface and now VSCode sees it as global. thanks.

Answer (score -2):

> . I realize I can probably modify this file, but was looking for a better way (abstraction)

Have a file called `globals.d.ts`. This pattern is documented here : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/globals.html

Comment: I read your book over the last 3 days! Very impressive! I have also been reading about your Typescript Collections project (can't seem to find online docs). Is the name 'global.d.ts' special to TypeScript? Is there any difference than using i.e. interfaces.d.ts? Thanks

Comment: No. Nothing special in the name. Just a convention

Comment: I noticed you don't document how to acutally wire in a user-defined global.d.ts file.  Can you please elaborate?